# Neo4j: Creating different kind of shapes for nodes

Tags: d3.js, neo4j

With Neo4j we can create nodes with shape circle. But how can I create nodes such as Squarer, Cube types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Neo4j browser only has a single shape. You'll have to build your own visualization to get anything further.

Possible starting points for building such a visualization include:

- [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) (you already put the tag on the question)
- [vis.js](http://visjs.org/)
- [Cytoscape](http://js.cytoscape.org/)
- [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/)
- [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us/toolkit/)
- and more

Comment: How can I build my own visualization ? Could you share more info?

Comment: You put the d3.js tag on the question, so I guess you already have an idea. A quick Google search also has [vis.js](http://visjs.org/), [Cytoscape](http://js.cytoscape.org/), [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) or [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us/toolkit/) as possible starting points (there are even more).